# Sending emojis using sms gateway to mobile

Tags: c#, wpf, emoji

I am sending regular sms through sms gateaway's API. Is there any possibility to send unicode emojis to android phone?

Everything I see is just "Test??????" where ? supposed to be the emoji.

I can see the emoji like this :

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Emoji bikingEmoji = new Emoji(0x1F6B4);

        MessageBox.Show("Hello there is " + bikingEmoji);

    }

    public class Emoji
    {
        readonly int[] codes;
        public Emoji(int[] codes)
        {
            this.codes = codes;
        }

        public Emoji(int code)
        {
            codes = new int[] { code };
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (codes == null)
                return string.Empty;

            var sb = new StringBuilder(codes.Length);

            foreach (var code in codes)
                sb.Append(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(code));

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Although I don't see it in perfect format, I do see the emoji. Sadly I don't see that when I am trying to send it through api

Comment: Is the emoji visible in the set of characters of your android? I found a list here where your example emoji isnt listed: https://emojipedia.org/google/ . Perhaps try a more common one like the simple smiling face

Comment: @Chrᴉz I was trying many of them. There is got to be something wrong with the formating because phone can't translate it. I just tried the grinning face and i am still seeing this message on my phone: test??

Comment: A unicode character is two bytes.  You are sending : 0x1F6B4 which is three bytes?  This is binary so you need to convert to bytes using encoding : Encoding.Unicode.ToString(new byte[] {0x01, 0xF6, 0xB4});

Comment: I am sorry @jdweng I am quite newbie it says that : _No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments_

Comment: I can't find the constructor on the web to give answer.  I suspect it takes two parameters 1) Name 2) Bytes.

Comment: @Cabry I guess jdweng meant `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString((new byte[] { 0x01, 0xF6, 0xB4 }))`

Comment: @Chrᴉz No, it is not working for me. Still getting ?? in phone sms.

Comment: I found a [wikipedia entry here that might help you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) . Have you tried to copy the used emoji into an sms on your smartphone? Does this work? Messager(Whatsapp/Telegram) != SMS. Good luck!